# Web: How often does Flask/JS refresh?

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, flask, python-3.6

I'm trying to get images to display in real-time only on my machine.  Think a really basic version of Google Images.  The user types in "red hammer" and I show them a picture of red hammer

The problem is the refresh rate.  I update the image file to be shown, and when I look it up directly as `http://127.0.0.1:6007/static/tree.jpg`, that will immediately give me the most recent jpg.  And then, strangely enough after I look up something like `http://127.0.0.1:6007/static/tree.jpg`, the image changes on the initial `http://127.0.0.1:6007` !

#### My setup:

In the `static/` directory, `tree.jpg`:

[image: img]

## templates/

#### show.html

In `templates/`, `show.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Text-to-Image Synthesis</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/generator">
      <p>Input to Generator: <input type="text" name="input_text"><input type="submit" value="Generate Image"></p>
    </form>
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='tree.jpg')}}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

#### index.html

and `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Text-to-Image Synthesis</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/generator">
<!-- button  -->
      <p>Input to Generator: <input type="text" name="input_text"><input type="submit" value="Generate Image"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

These two are the same except `show.html` shows the image on the `src=...` line.

## server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, g, redirect, Response, send_from_directory

tmpl_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=tmpl_dir)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/generator', methods=['POST'])
def generator():
    # save typed-in text
    text = request.form['input_text']
    filename = "/home/ubuntu/icml2016/scripts/cub_queries.txt"
    with open(filename, "a+") as f:
        f.write(text + "\n")

    """
    print('start')
    subprocess.call('./scripts/demo_cub.sh', shell=True) # change the image in the background
    print('end')
    """

    return render_template("show.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST='0.0.0.0'
    PORT=6007
    app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

So now if I've properly given you everything, you should be able to call `python3 server.py` and see this:
 [image]

and if you type in "hi" to the box it'll show this:

[image]

but when I change tree.jpg to some other image in the background and type in something else, I don't get the instant image update I'm looking for.  In other words, that tree won't become the most recent tree :(   We want to see Maury's beautiful face on my basic webpage

[image]

Comment: Can you disable browser cache and try reloading ?

Comment: I think this helped, but I think a good portion of the problem is that /generator doesn't refresh the page when it calls itself after you type in a query.  So `show.html` calls generator() again which keeps show.html from reloading?  But I'm new to Flask and webdev, so I'm not sure if that's right

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relates to http caching - read about the http Expires header. Flask defaults to setting an Expires header of 12 hours. This instructs your web browser that there is no need to ask for tree.jpg again for 12 hours. When your browser needs tree.jpg again it will simply load it from cache, it will not even make a request to your server. Manually entering this tree.jpg URL in your browser overrides this, in doing so you ask your browser to request it again.

You don't appear to have provided the relevant code -- the `send_from_directory` call serving your static file is where you need to make change.

`send_from_directory(directory, filename, cache_timeout=0)`

Relevant documentation:

- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory
- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file
- and `send_file_max_age` on the same page (the default Expiry)

Comment: I am not using `send_from_directory()`.  I am using `render_from_template()` and hard-coding the file instead.  But perhaps I *should* use `send_from_directory()` instead?  `render_from_template()` doesn't have the flag `cache_timeout` you mention

Comment: Ah, yes. I woukd not use a render template method on a binary file. That is creating unnecessary work. You imported send_from_directory explicitly - I thought you must have had a /static route using this. It will be an Expires issue. A good way to debug is Chrome's developer tools. Use the network timeline to inspect the headers of each request/response.

Comment: I am now trying to use `flask_cache.Cache` and clear it manually with `cache.clear()` each time I need to re-do `render_template('show.html')` .  But it's not working.  Developer tools worked, but this will not be allowed when I present this project

Comment: The reason I am using `render_template()` repeatedly is I want to display the text box and uploaded image each time

Comment: The way you have implemented the client must receive two files for each update - show.html and *.jpg. These are two http requests. Currently your browser often caches the *.jpg request - so doesn't ask the server for it again. To ensure the client web browser always asks for the image again, you must set a header indicating that file has immediately expired.

Comment: Also note - you are conflating server side caching and client side caching. The cache you refered to above is a server side cache. It cannot change the client cache.